# error updating DynamoDB Table: Table already has an enabled stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am defining a dynamo table and trigger like this:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "filenames" {
  name           = local.dynamodb_table_filenames
  billing_mode   = "PROVISIONED"
  read_capacity  = 1000
  write_capacity = 1000
  hash_key       = "filename"
  stream_enabled = true
  stream_view_type = "NEW_IMAGE"

  #range_key      = ""

  attribute {
    name = "filename"
    type = "S"
  }

  tags = var.tags
}


resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "allow_dynamodb_table_to_trigger_lambda" {
  event_source_arn  = aws_dynamodb_table.filenames.stream_arn
  function_name     = aws_lambda_function.trigger_stepfunction_lambda.arn
  starting_position = "LATEST"
}
```

Upon running `terraform apply`, I get the following error:

```
error updating DynamoDB Table (xzy): ValidationException: Table already has an enabled stream: TableName: 4 xzy
```

I didn't see this error before I added `stream_enabled` and `stream_view_type`. If I remove these two attributes, I will get another error so I cannot remove them.

Comment: Have you enabled DynamoDB streams manually on the table from AWS console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dynamo db Stream It might have been enabled from the beigining
You cant change parameter of `stream_view_type` already enabled dynamodb stream, dynamodb doucmention didnt mentioned it.

I suggest you Create a new table and enable the dyanmodb `stream_enabled: true` and  `stream_view_type:[]` both at once.